# Check when countdown expired

Tags: javascript, php

I've managed to came out a code that can start a dynamic countdown on Javascript using user based input.

1)However when I try to input his to check for countdown expired, It's innerhtml not working...

2)Is it possible to store the countdown timer as persistent cookies with unique key? So the next time when I open, the countdown will be there based on unique key.

My check time function

```
function checkTime() {
 var time = document.getElementById('strclock').innerHTML;
 if(time != '00:00:00') {
  //execute some SQL statement
 }elseif(time == '00:00:00'){
  //execute some SQL statement
 }
```

My dynamic countdown timer

```
<div id="strclock"></div>
<div id="clock"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var hour = <?php echo floor($hours); ?>;
 var min = <?php echo floor($minutes); ?>;
 var sec = <?php echo floor($seconds); ?>;
```

**(Function checkTime() will be inserted here)**

```
function countdown() {
    if(sec <= 0 && min > 0) {
        sec = 60;
        min -= 1;
    }
    else if(min <= 0 && sec <= 0) {
        min = 0;
        sec = 0;
    }
    else {
        sec -= 1;
    }
    if(min <= 0 && hour > 0) {
        min = 60;
        hour -= 1;
    }
    var pat = /^[0-9]{1}$/;
    secs = (pat.test(sec) == true) ? '0'+sec : sec;
    mins = (pat.test(min) == true) ? '0'+min : min;
    hours = (pat.test(hour) == true) ? '0'+hour : hour;

    document.getElementById('strclock').innerHTML = hours+":"+mins+":"+secs;
    if(hour >= 1) { 
           document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = hour+1+' hour until timer runs out!';
    } 
    else if(min >= 1) {
           document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = min+' minute until timer runs out!';
    }
    else {
           document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = sec+' seconds until timer runs out!';
    }
    setTimeout("countdown()",1000);
    }
    countdown();
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's not working? What is not working about it?

Comment: You are mixing `javascript` up with `php`.... `echo "Test";` isn't valid in `javascript`.  **echo** is `php`. If you open your browser console I'm sure you will find an error in there. `php` executes on the server way before javascript is used placing php in a javascript function will not execute a database query.

Comment: Where do you call your ```checkTime``` function?

Comment: After I input the checkTime() function inside, the timer went missing. The time was shown before checkTime() function.

I would like to do something if the countdown timer is expired.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to Your problem is as follows. Only difference is that inside function I'm checking for  `document.getElementById('strclock').innerHTML` and if it is equal to 00:00:00 I'm alerting stop. In place of alert you can call your function.
Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/himanshu9419/pen/OOzZQO) link

Only thing which you need to add for this is

```
if(time == '00:00:00') {alert("stop")}
        else{ setTimeout("countdown()",1000);}
```

After adding this your code will work fine.

```
 <div id="strclock"></div>
    <div id="clock"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     var hour = <?php echo floor($hours); ?>;
     var min = <?php echo floor($minutes); ?>;
     var sec = <?php echo floor($seconds); ?>;

    function countdown() {
        if(sec <= 0 && min > 0) {
            sec = 60;
            min -= 1;
        }
        else if(min <= 0 && sec <= 0) {
            min = 0;
            sec = 0;
        }
        else {
            sec -= 1;
        }
        if(min <= 0 && hour > 0) {
            min = 60;
            hour -= 1;
        }
        var pat = /^[0-9]{1}$/;
        secs = (pat.test(sec) == true) ? '0'+sec : sec;
        mins = (pat.test(min) == true) ? '0'+min : min;
        hours = (pat.test(hour) == true) ? '0'+hour : hour;

        document.getElementById('strclock').innerHTML = hours+":"+mins+":"+secs;
        if(hour >= 1) { 
               document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = hour+1+' hour until timer runs out!';
        } 
        else if(min >= 1) {
               document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = min+' minute until timer runs out!';
        }
        else {
               document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = sec+' seconds until timer runs out!';
        }
        if(time == '00:00:00') {alert("stop")}
        else{ setTimeout("countdown()",1000);}
        }
        countdown();
    </script>
```